# jQuery - Stop function being triggered again until it's stopped running

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of code that basically zooms into an image on mouseover and then resets on mouseleave.

My only issue is that if you mouseover/leave quickly the function runs and runs and runs that many times.

Is there any way to prevent the function from firing if it's currently animating?

I understand this can be done with CSS but I need to be able to support all browsers back to IE8 so that's not an option (Annoyingly)

Thanks!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.image img').on("mouseover", function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: "110%",
                width: "110%",
                marginLeft: "-5%",
                marginTop: "-5%"
            }, 1000);
        });

        $('.image img').on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                marginLeft: "0%",
                marginTop: "0%"
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to stop the queuing up of animation. It should be done like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.image img').on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this)
        .stop(true, false)
        .animate({
            height: "110%",
            width: "110%",
            marginLeft: "-5%",
            marginTop: "-5%"
        }, 1000);
    });

    $('.image img').on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this)
        .stop(true, false)
        .animate({
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            marginLeft: "0%",
            marginTop: "0%"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

The first parameter of `.stop` is `clearQueue` and second is `jumpToEnd`

Comment: This is perfect!   I'll give you the answer when it lets me :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is to dynamically bind and unbind the mouseover and mouseleave functions. To do this, simply start with `mouseleave` unbound and `mouseover` bound.

In the beginning of the body of `mouseover`, bind `mouseleave` and unbind `mouseover`.

In the beginning of the body of `mouseleave`, bind `mouseover` and unbind `mouseleave`.

This should solve the problem.